# Prove that the sequence is decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a>1$ , $n \geq 2$ be fixed and $\{a_k\}_{k\geq 0} $ be the the sequence defined as follows: $$a_0: =a\\a_{k+1} = \frac{1} {n}\left((n-1)a_k + \frac{a} {(a_k)^{n-1} }\right) $$
I need to prove that this is a decreasing sequence. I know that $\forall k \geq 0 \;  a_k^n > a \implies \{a_k\}_{k \geq 0} $ is a decreasing sequence. 
But I am stuck at the $\forall k \geq 0 \;  a_k^n > a$ part. Actually I don't know whether it's a decreasing sequence but the computation seems to suggest so.

Comment: What if we add this condition(a >1).

Comment: You've actually got it solved, I think.  If $f(x)=\frac1n((n-1)x +ax^{1-n})$, it's enough to show $f'(x)\geq0$ for $x\geq a$.  This comes down to showing $x^n\geq a$ and this is clear since $x\geq a\geq 1$.